# Linq dynamic query (Except - but SQL SERVER side)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to return records where the date column is greater than `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)`, but only if the type column is complete. 
Meaning, I want to return everything except for records that are older than 3 days and the type is == complete (Enum 1).

It's almost as if I need Except, but for that, I'd need to enumerate the results, then I wouldn't have my page number of results (.Take(10)).

How would this be done in linq? I can't figure out how this query would look. I would like the query to be done SQL SERVER side as much as possible as to be efficient.

Just to be clear - I want **all** results, **EXCEPT** records that are completed and older than 3 days.

(completed meaning the type column value == 1 (Enum))

My project is .NetCore 3.1

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `Except`, but `Where`. Post your entity class for more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be this that you need ?

```
  Var results = context.Entity.Where(x=> x.Type != enum.Completed ||( x.Type == enum.Completed && x.Date >=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)));
```

Comment: Thanks, Stefano, but I do want to include completed records as long as they're newer than DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3). In addition to all other records. The query above would ensure NO completed records would be returned at all.

Comment: So you want the completed record only if the are newer than 3 days i got it right?
I've edited the answer for that case

Comment: Yes but in addition to every other record in that table regardless of if it is completed. I see that you just updated your answer to reflect this, and I think that's it! I think you cracked it. Thanks Stefano!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Results = context.Entity.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) || x.Type != YourEnum.Complete);
```

Comment: Thanks Matthijs, but I do want other records that are older than 3 days. It's just the completed records that I want to apply the 'older than 3-day clause' to. If that makes sense.

Comment: You will get all records where the type is something else than complete, independent of date (it is an OR) but if type == complete, then date needs to be newer than 3 days old

Comment: But your suggestion filters out all completed records, regardless of date?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you mean by "type" column, but I am guessing is the value of the object you are after.

Then you should probably do something like :

```
var dateRange = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
var results = _repository.Entity.Where(w => w.Date >= date && w.Type != null);
```

Comment: I just have a column called Type. The problem is, I want to return all records, but if a record's Type is equal to Complete (Enum(1)) and older than 3 days, I don't want it. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sure @Stefanos, it's as simple as this at the moment. //All results, apart from results that are completed (Enum 1) and older than 3 days.
Approvals.Where(*some condition*).Take(10).ToList()

Comment: You can do
var results = _repository.Entity.Where(w => w.Date >= date && w.Type != enumName.Complete);

If w.Type is a string, remember that you need to convert the enum to string by adding ".ToString()"

Comment: Thanks @Stefanos, but I do want completed records that are newer than -3 days - just not older than -3 days, in addition to the rest of the records.